# Heat equation in 1D with collocation method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to use the collocation method to solve $u_t=u_{xx}$. I impose the PDE pointwise and expand the solution in Fourier Series:
$$ \partial_{t}\sum_{k=-K}^{K}\hat{u}_{k}(t)\ e^{ikx_{l}}-\partial_{x}^{2}\sum_{k=-K}^{K}\hat{u}_{k}(t)\ e^{ikx_{l}}=0$$
$$\sum_{k=-K}^{K}\frac{d}{dt}\hat{u}_{k}(t)\ e^{ikx_{l}}+\sum_{k=-K}^{K}k^{2}\hat{u}_{k}(t)\ e^{ikx_{l}}=0,\ \ \ \mbox{for }\ l=0,...,N-1$$
$$ A\frac{d}{dt}\hat{\mathbf{u}}+B\hat{\mathbf{u}} =0$$
$$\hat{\mathbf{u}}=\hat{\mathbf{u}}(0)\ e^{A^{-1}Bt}$$
How do I carry on? How are exactly the matrices $A$ and $B$ constructed, and is it worth trying to manipulate the matrix exponential?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't in any way a complete answer, but my low reputation wouldn't let me comment. $\mathbf{A}$ will have the form $A_{jq}=e^{i(q-K-1)x_j}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ will be $B_{jq}=q^2e^{i(q-K-1)x_j}$. Did you manage to get any further? I am trying to tackle a similar looking problem.